# Are there other examples for the subdivision with definite articles

Tags: articles

[i] Use ‘at’ with points of time in the day: at dawn
[ii] Use ‘in’ with parts of the day: in the morning ([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in_1))

They are saying that prepositions, *at* and *in,* are selected by their complements’ meaning: that is, exactly when or a period of time. So it has ‘at’ in [i], while ‘in’ in [ii]. And in the same line, it needs not to be a definite article in [i], it seems. Then, do we have to have the article in [ii] for subdividing a period of time, like as subdividing cake into pieces? If it’s the reason why ‘the’ is used, are there any other examples for the subdivision with definite articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules when the definite article should be used, and when not, are very fuzzy and often derived from tradition. Note,

> at dawn
>
> at the break of dawn.
>
> at noon
>
> at high noon
>
> tomorrow [no article nor preposition!]
>
> the day after tomorrow [article but no preposition!]
>
> in the evening [period, with 'in']
>
> at night [period, with 'at']
>
> during the day [neither 'at' nor 'on' work here]
>
> on July, the 4th
>
> in July
>
> on day five (of our journey)

If a rule exists, it's surely very complex and full of exceptions. I think it's best to learn these 'by ear'.